# How to assign a Site Role for user in Liferay

Tags: liferay, hook, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-aui

I am creating the users programatically and trying to assign the site role programatically. I need to assign the "Site Administration" role for a user. So I tried as follows,

```
 Role role = RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRole(companyId, "Site Administrator");
   System.out.println("Role Id is !! " + role.getRoleId());
   UserLocalServiceUtil.addRoleUser(role.getRoleId(), newUser.getUserId());
   UserLocalServiceUtil.updateUser(newUser);
```

From the above code, The "Site Administration" role is assigned as a "Regular Role". I need the "Site Administration" role is assigned as a "Site Role".

Any suggestion how can I assign the role as a Site Role?

Comment: Do you two "Site Administrator" roles defined? One as regular and one for site.

Comment: No only one that is for site. But while assigning the role is assigned under the Regular Role. May be the way I am wring the logic is incorrect. So can you please suggest me how can I assign the site administration role under Site Role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use UserGroupRoleLocalServiceUtil.java's API method as below.

```
public static void addUserGroupRoles(long userId, long groupId,
        long[] roleIds)
```